# Image doesn't show in Wordpress but does in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a div with a background image and text inside, but this doesn't show in Wordpress. However it works fine in HTML/CSS, as you can see here https://fiddle.jshell.net/tLavv0w1/

When I try to look at the code in Firefox developer tools, the CSS doesn't show. So it seems that the CSS doesn't connect with the HTML at all. I have also tried to change the div's name but it didn't work. I don't even know where to look for clues. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing http://localhost/ so when run locally, it works, but when run on the server, it won't. Change the URLs to legit URLs

https://fiddle.jshell.net/tLavv0w1/3/

Comment: I'm new to HTML/CSS. What do you mean by changing to legit URLs?

Comment: Look at my example. Localhost is your local computer. You need to reference a public and accessible image if you expect everyone to view it. Have you uploaded the image to the site? What is the URL of the image? Use that, better yet, use src="/wp-content/...." as the URL rather than adding the domain name

Comment: While I work on the website, I have to use localhost.

Comment: The problem is not the URL, it seems to be the CSS. Because regardless of the type of image/URL I insert to the div, it will not show.

Comment: No, it is the URL

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing [`localhost`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) which means "the computer I am currently on".

If you change the URL to an image found online, it works.

See here: https://fiddle.jshell.net/tLavv0w1/1/

(I just used your stackoverflow image URL by right clicking it and "copy image address" -- this is what address it gave me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3nvj.jpg?s=32&g=1)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Through Firefox developer tools, I found out that a comment tag before the CSS wasn't closed. It's now closed!